# my carousel directly of the bootstrap 5.2 page not working

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

i'm using the carousel of the code placed in (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/carousel/)

```
        <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <img src="assets/vscode.png" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="assets/ms-vs.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <img src="assets/intellij.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
              </div>
            </div>
            <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
              <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
            </button>
            <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
              <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
              <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
            </button>
          </div>
```

but the bottoms not working in my browser(mozilla firefox), someone can to explain me the why, i'm begginer
have a nice day/afternoon/night.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't have to tell us to ignore code. Edit your question to remove the code we don't need. We also do not know what "not working" means. Is there a browser error? Is the CSS not applied? Also, did you include the Bootstrap CSS and JS files in your project?

Comment: not, is only the code in that page, the project is of my college and i can only use html, css and bootstrap, the carousel is working, but the botoms not.

Comment: Bottom? Are you talking about the `<buttons>`?

Comment: buttons, excuse me, english is not my native language

Comment: I copied the code here and added the bootstrap css and js files and everything works as expected. Are you sure there's not an error in the rest of your code somewhere?

Comment: there are any way to you give me the code?

Comment: All I did was copy the CDN links for the CSS/JS from here: https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/ and used your code above. I did not change anything else. Copy the CSS and JS links and paste them above your code. If your carousel works, just not the buttons, there is something else going on.